# How to use . (dot) character in regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

Please explain . dot regular expression

```
public class ExampleRegex {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my text";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean isMatch = EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("\\.");
        System.out.println(isMatch);
    }
}
```

What should be string that matches \. regex

Comment: .......... <-- There's ten of them

Comment: *Please* try Google, and SO, before asking.

Answer (score 4):

An *escaped* dot as you have will only match another literal dot. An unescaped dot will match any character except newlines (though that can be configured using the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag).

```
"."    // unescaped, matches any character
"\\."  // escaped, only matches "."
```

It might behoove you to read the [Java tutorial on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

The dot character matches any character. If you want to match a literal dot, you should use `\\.`.

If your question is how to match a `\` followed by a `.`, you should use `\\\\.` in Java.
That's because `\` is an escape String both in Java and in Java Regex, so you must repeat it four times.

Comment: Are you sure about your edit? `\\\\.` will match \ and any character. I guess the purpose is to match \ and . together, so he should use: `\\\\\\.`.